# RStudio in Rserver, disable idle timeout on ShinyApp

Tags: r, shiny, r-server

When running my ShinyApp locally, the webpage interactivity never shutdowns (turns grey and takes no user input). When running this same app in browser r-server RStudio, app shutdowns in a minute or so.

Any dummy server would do, but for example

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  h1("Example"),
  inputPanel(
    actionButton("button", "This is button")
  )
  
)
server <- function(input, output){
  observeEvent(input$button,
                print("Button pressed.")
  )
}
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

follows the described behavior.

How do I disable or bypass this?

Answer (score 3):

This might depend on your server - do you experience the same issue when publishing to [shinyapps](https://www.shinyapps.io)? If not, it could be an issue with the RStudio server setup.

Either way, take a look at the [configuration reference](https://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#application-timeouts):

3.3 Application Timeouts

**app_idle_timeout** -- Defines the amount of time (in seconds) an R process with no active connections should remain open. After the last connection disconnects from an R process, this timer will start and, after the specified number of seconds, if no new connections have been created, the R process will be killed. The default value for **app_idle_timeout** is 5 seconds. Setting **app_idle_timeout** to 0 will disable the app idle time out.

EDIT: In case it is your RStudio server, take a look at **/etc/rstudio/rsession.conf** - especially `session-timeout-minutes=nn` ([Reference](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200552316-Configuring-the-Server)).

Comment: I have no knowledge of anyone publishing from our system. It is a closed one. Do these timeouts apply to free version of R server? I assumed paid version to be but this might not be the case after-all.